# Fix an orphaned user with a slash in the name?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, database-administration

How do you fix an orphaned user with a slash in the name?  This code works for users without a slash in their name.

```
EXEC sp_change_users_login @Action='update_one', @UserNamePattern='[acc\windows_groupAccounting]', 
   @LoginName='[acc\windows_groupAccounting]';
```

**Error:**

> Terminating this procedure. The User name '[acc\windows_groupAccounting]' is absent or invalid.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I tried both, with and without and I get the same error.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you show the output of `EXEC sys.sp_change_users_login @Action = N'REPORT';`?

Comment: HI @AaronBertrand, there is only one user with it's SID (not the user in question).  I didn't know this until today, but the user was dropped and recreated so the SID's match now. 

I use a script with a bunch of the sp_change_users_login SP specified for each user when I restore a database.  I was trying to script out a user with a slash to add to that script.  If there's a better way, I'm open to it.  The DB's are restored infrequently and manually when requested.

Comment: This may be useful: https://am2.co/2021/07/dba-serverlogins/ or this: https://sqlsoldier.net/wp/sqlserver/transferring-logins-to-a-database-mirror